How can I find out what the most lightweight terminal emulator is?
I am trying to reduce the disk space by my system, by removing packages I don't or rarely use, as well as the RAM needed for my programs and background tasks. I need the terminal mostly for displaying various things (calendar, actual time, output of some shell/bash commands, etc.). I'm using gnome-terminal right now, but this ought to be done smarter (here: more resource efficient).
Mainly, I don't really need a colourful output, so I thought about xterm doing this, but I couldn't manage transferring the command(s) I'm using with gnome-terminal to another terminal emulator.
The first question would be here:
How can I find out which is the most lightweight terminal emulator for use with a window manager (not a full desktop environment)?
Here's a code snippet from my rc.xml of my window manager openbox:
<keybind key="W-l">
  <action name="Execute">
    <startupnotify>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </startupnotify>
    <command>sh -c 'echo "$(date)\t\tbeginning of session lock" &gt;&gt; ~/.lock.log; i3lock -uc 000000'</command>
  </action>
</keybind>

<keybind key="W-c">
  <action name="Execute">
    <startupnotify>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
      <name>Kalender</name>
    </startupnotify>
    <shade>no</shade>
    <command>gnome-terminal --hide-menubar --window-with-profile=calendar --title='calendar month' --geometry=66x9 -- bash -c 'ncal -C3; read -sn1'</command>
  </action>
</keybind>

<keybind key="W-S-d">
  <action name="Execute">
    <startupnotify>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </startupnotify>
    <command>lxterminal --geometry=40x32 -t "To Do's" -e "vi ~/todo"</command>
  </action>
</keybind>

I rewrote the code for very simple commands like the first shortcut, but I didn't manage to "convert" the second shortcut into the form of the third one.

"I couldn't manage transferring the command(s) I'm using with gnome-terminal to another terminal" -- Could you please elaborate? What do you do exactly, and what unexpected result occurs? Advanced features of terminals might be different, but the basics are the very same, you should be able to easily replace any terminal with any other and perform the same tasks inside.

Not displaying colors is not where you're going to save a notable amount of resources.

Unless you're working with embedded systems with very limited technical capabilities, one terminal emulator or another won't make much difference in terms of CPU and RAM.

You don't need full GNOME for gnome-terminal though. I've been using it with i3 for years.

@egmont That's not my only concern.
TomYan I know this, thank you anyhow.

If you want to save on resources, changing one terminal emulator for another won't really change much. If you really want to go frugal, skip the graphical interface altogether.
To experiment, you could try running a basic version of AlpineLinux from a USB stick. That really doesn't require much from your system.

That would be too little graphical. What about viewing images, pdf files, watching videos or webbrowsing…? This isn't (or hardly) possible without using a display manager, is it?

If you have enough HW resources to browse the web, view images and watch videos, then you have more than enough resources to run dozens of (different) terminal emulators without worrying about the overhead.
I don't want to sound condescending. There are instances when the overhead of running a graphical terminal emulator can be relevant. But that's when you're running embedded systems, or working with vintage (20th century) computers.

As per the downvotes and the comments, you are asking the wrong question/trying to solve the wrong problem. You should start by learning a little about memory is managed on Linux, notably how copy-on-write and dynamic linking works. If you are using gnome-terminal as the only GTK executable on the host, then there will be significant savings switching to another terminal emulator. OTOH if you're already running lots of GTK/Gnome stuff then even a very memory efficient emulator will probably result in more RAM being used.
A consequence of all the clever stuff built into Linux for memory management is that its actually very difficult to answer the question "How much memory does _____ use?". The simplest solution is to compare the output of "free" before and while the program is running (exactly how you run free without starting a terminal emulator is a simple exercise for you to think about).
